# MySql Statistics during a time interval

Tags: mysql, statistics

I have a table in which I record the execution of some tasks. In one column I display either the result of the execution, or if the execution is not successful I display an error message, like: "Error X: ...". I also have a column in which I save the date of the execution. I already run the task for few months. I now need to make statistics about the number of errors and the number of successful tasks day by day for the previous months. How can this be done ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select count(*) as err_cnt, DATE_FORMAT(date_column, "%Y-%m-%d") as date_day from stats_table where left(data, 5) = "Error" group by date_day
```

If you do not have column with date it's impossible

Comment: Thank you. If I also want to count the number of good results (or since they don't a specific syntax, the total number of results instead) side by side with the number of errors, how can this be done ? So something like:

err_cnt  all_cnt date
1            4    2016-01-01
0            8    2016-01-02

Comment: It's possible, but due to performance it's better to run 1 more query and combine results. For retrieve all count need to remove where statement, and good count will be `all_cnt - err_cnt`